# Как обработать заказ через телеграмм бота на python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть бот который принимает заказы от пользователей (бот для кафе)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После приема заказа бот отправляет его в чат админов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вопрос заключается в том, как сделать так чтобы ответ с кнопок из группы отправлялся пользователю

Answer (score 1):

Возможно стоит попробовать:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])

def answer_to_order(message):
    if message.text == 'Принят':
        bot.send_message(customer_id, 'Ваш заказ был принят , ожидайте...')
    
    else:
        bot.send_message(customer_id, 'Ваш заказ был отклонён')
```

Суть состоит в том , что бот будет проверять ответ от админов , и в зависимости от ответа бот отправляет пользователю текст